# Novice programmer needs advice: "String index out of range" - Java

Tags: java, string, indexing, range

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm getting a error which I'm sure is a easy fix for more experienced people.

Here is what I have:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ReadNamesFile
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // make the names.csv comma-separated-values file available for reading
        FileReader f = new FileReader("names.csv");
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(f);
        //
        String lastName="unknown", firstName="unknown", office="unknown";

        // get first line
        String line = r.readLine();

        // process lines until end-of-file occurs
        while ( line != null )
        {
           // get the last name on the line
           //
           // position of first comma
           int positionOfComma = line.indexOf(","); 
           // extract the last name as a substring
           lastName = line.substring(0,positionOfComma); 
           // truncate the line removing the name and comma
           line = line.substring(positionOfComma+1); 

           // extract the first name as a substring
           firstName = line.substring(0,positionOfComma); 
           // truncate the line removing the name and comma
           line = line.substring(positionOfComma+1);

           // extract the office number as a substring
           office = line.substring(0,positionOfComma);
           // truncate the line removing the name and comma
           line = line.substring(positionOfComma+2);
           //
           //        
           //
           // display the information about each person
           System.out.print("\nlast name = "+lastName);
           System.out.print("\t first name = "+firstName);
           System.out.print("\t office = "+office);
           System.out.println();
           //
           // get the next line
           line = r.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, it finds the last name, first name and office number in a .csv file and prints them out.

When I compile I don't get any errors but when I run it I get:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1955)
at ReadNamesFile.main(ReadNamesFile.java:34)
```

Before trying to do the office number part, the first two (last and first name) printed out fine but the office number doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Edit: Thanks for all the posts guys, I still can't really figure it out though. Can someone post something really dumbed down? I've been trying to fix this for an hour now and I can't get it.

Comment: It would be helpful to note which line is line 34.

Comment: Advice: 1) Read the error message. Love the error message. Where does it come from? What does it mean? 2) Use a debugger and stop on the exception; what are the current values that make it explode? Why are they so and not expected "valid" values?

Answer (score 1):

Let's work by example, what issues you have with your code.

> Eg: line: Overflow,stack
>   { length: 14 }

Taking your program statements line by line -

```
int positionOfComma = line.indexOf(",");  // returns 9

lastName = line.substring(0,positionOfComma); // should be actually postionOfComma-1
```

Now lastName has `Overflow`. positionOfComma has `9`.

```
line = line.substring(positionOfComma+1);
```

Now `line` has `stack`.

```
firstName = line.substring(0,positionOfComma);
```

Asking substring from **0** to **9**. But `stack` is only of length **5**. This will cause **String index out of range exeception**. Hope you understood where you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html):

> (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException) - Thrown by String methods to
>   indicate that an index is either negative or greater than the size of
>   the string.

In your case, one of your calls to `.substring` is being given a value that is `>=` the length of the string. If line #34 is a comment, then it's the line above #34.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

a) Make sure you handle the case if you DON'T find a comma (i.e. if you cannot find and extract a lastName and/or firstName string)

b) Make sure the value of "positionOfComma + N" never exceeds the length of the string.

A couple of "if" blocks and/or "continue" statements will do the trick nicely ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You correctly find `positionOfComma`, but then that logic applies to the original value of `line`.  When you remove the last name and comma, `positionOfComma` is no longer correct as it applies to the old value of line.

Answer (score 0):

```
int positionOfComma = line.indexOf(",");
```

this line of code might not find a comma and then positionOfComma will be -1.  Next you substring something with (0,-1) - eeek no wonder it gives StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.  Use something like:

```
int positionOfComma = 0;
if(line.indexOf(",")!=-1)
{
   positionOfComma = line.indexOf(",");
}
```

You do have to do lots of checking of things sometimes especially when the data is whacked :(

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)

PS I'm sure someone clever can make my coding look shabby but you get the point I hope :)